# Getting data from dynamic mongodb embedded object node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I have a mongoDB structure that looks like this:

```
values : { [
oneValue : {
     number: '20'
     unit: 'g'
}
differentValue : {
    number : '30'
    unit : 'g'
}
]}
```

I am using node js this is what I do:

```
doc.values.forEach(function(err, idx) {

var object = doc.values[idx];
}
```

And what ends up happening is I can get an object that looks like this:

```
object = oneValue : {
     number: '20'
     unit: 'g'
}
```

But node does not recognize it as a JSON because when I try to do JSON.parse(object) it doesn't know how to handle it.

I want to be able to get at the number field dynamically.  So I don't want to say doc.values[idx].oneValue because this is a pretend case and in the real case oneValue could be one of 1000 different things.  Does anyone know how I can access the 'number' field with this structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out...

after

```
var object = docs.values[idx]
```

do this:

```
var objAsJson = JSON.stringify(object);
JSON.parse(objAsJson, function(k, v) {
console.log(k + "  " + v);
});
```

That will print out all the data in the embedded object and you don't have to know the name.